# How create a double IF condition in Javascript/Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In this example I access the runtime function twice
the first time the function works normally,
and the second time it replaces template1 with data from template2.

Help us solve this problem.

```
<template>
  <div>

<v-runtime-template :template="template1"></v-runtime-template>
<v-runtime-template :template="template2"></v-runtime-template>

  </div>
</template>


<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";
import axios from 'axios'
export default {

    data: () => ({
      x: 0, y: 0,
            template: null,
      template1: null,
      template2: null,
    }),
    components: {
    VRuntimeTemplate,
  },

    mounted() {
        let vm = this
    vm.runtime();

    },
    methods: {

    runtime(){
        /*  if the condition is correct assign
range of indexes of the second block */
      if (this.x == -1){this.x = 11; this.y = 24;}

        /*  and if this condition is correct we assign
         index range of the first block */
      if (this.x == 0){this.x = -1; this.y = 12;}

this.template = `
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div v-for="(mult, index) in mults">
         <div v-if="(index > x & index < y)">
            <div class="card">
            <!--       -->
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>`;

    /* find out which block was formed
         and assign the generated block to the first one
         or the second template */
if (this.x == 11){this.template2 = this.template;}
if (this.x == -1){this.template1 = this.template;}

    /* there is an error here: I get two identical blocks */
    }
</script>
```

Why when x is 11,
the condition x == -1 is false, but it is met?
How do I configure the IF condition so that template1 doesn't change in the second run of the runtime () function ?

Answer (score 0):

In js `&` is used for [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND):

```js
console.log(3 & 5);
console.log(0b11 & 0b101);
```

What you want is [boolean AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), which in js is `&&`:

```js
console.log(true && false);
console.log(true && true);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what would it look like in my example?